# Rails Dynamic Form Fields & AJAX Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Ruby on Rails app that has a form with nested attributes. This form allows the dynamic addition of fields with some javascript. The form also submits itself on blur via AJAX.

Everything is working great, with the exception of one issue that centres around the dynamic addition of fields.

When the dynamic fields are added via Javascript, they are assigned a unique ID. However, the ID and pattern of names for form fields obviously does not match what rails would generate once the fields have been saved.

Because of the AJAX form submit, the dynamically added fields create a new DB entry every time the form is changed.

I need to find a way to gracefully handle the fact that I need to retrieve the rails generated form and modify/replace the one on the page after an AJAX submit - otherwise new fields will continue to replicate!

You can see my code at: https://github.com/michaelward82/WeddingPlanner/tree/UI

(Apologies if my Rails code is not the cleanest, this is my first genuine attempt at a real rails project and I'm still learning the patterns)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to allow the creation of child records before the parent is created (via your AJAX requests)?

Comment: The parent is already created. A Budget is created at the same time as a user, and belong_to that user. Through the budget show action we use nested fields to allow budget items to be added to the budget.

The problem is that any dynamically added budget items are treated as new until the user refreshes the page and gets the form as generated by rails.

Refreshing the page or avoiding the use of AJAX doesn't feel like an elegant solution.

Comment: It sounds like you need `BudgetItems#new` to return the new object rendered without the layout, then your javascript can just replace that object's HTML on the page.

Comment: I found ways to return the entire form partial. That wasn't practical, as the form updates were too frequent. For the moment I have resigned myself to using a submit button and allowing rails to regenerate the form. I wasn't sure if the generated load from the AJAX autosave would be too much to handle regardless. Still if anyone can come up with an elegant solution...

Comment: I came across to a solution for a similar problem, maybe i can help. Can you provide the code again? the link is broken :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're missing is a `:dependent => :delete_all` parameter on the `belongs_to` association. That makes Rails delete the old budget items when a new set is saved:

```
# budget_item.rb
belongs_to :budget, :dependent => :delete_all
```